# fb app not requesting all permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions

I´ve written a facebook connector app which should request some permissions.
When I click the preview login dialog button in the applications edit menu all the permissions are listed but when I open the login dialog from my website only the standard permissions (general user information) are requested. I´ve already saved it several times and waited for hours but it doesn´t work.
Am I doing anything wrong or did I just discover a bug or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission settings in your Facebook application configuration only apply to auth dialogs from the Facebook app center. You need to specify the permissions you want when you are opening the login dialog from your website. For example, if you're using the Javascript SDK's FB.login to do login, you will need something like

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email,publish_actions'})
```

Pay particular attention to the scope parameter.

Comment: That works fine thanks.
But why do I have to add all of the permissions in the edit menu when I have to request them later on the website anyways?

Comment: The permissions in the edit menu are what will be used when the user installs your application via the Facebook App Center. If you aren't going to publish on the Facebook App Center, you don't need to enter permissions there at all.